# Recursively change the name of a file and the content inside the file if matches a keyword

Tags: linux, command-line-interface, sed

I can use sed to do recursively find and replace a string in a bunch of files. Like so:

```
find -name  "*.py"  -not \( -name .svn -prune \) -type f -print0  | xargs
-0  sed -i 's/cat/dog/g'
```

However is there a way to search for a string both inside a file and in the actual file names?

If the string is found in the name of a file, then replace the string in the file name with a new string.

If the string inside the actual file, then replace the string with a new string.

And of course, to search recursively.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how to do this in one go, but it can easily be accomplished as a small script, e.g. (lightly tested):

```
find -name  "*.py"  -not \( -name .svn -prune \) -type f -print0 \
| while read -r -d $'\0' filename; do
    sed -i 's/cat/dog/g' "$filename"
    echo "$filename" | grep -q "cat" \
    && mv "$filename" "${filename/cat/dog}"
  done
```